# How should I store the order of sortable elements on MySQL backend

Tags: php, mysql

Consider that I have two tables `surveys` and `surveyQuestions`

`surveys` has a primary index `surveyUniqueId`

`surveyQuestions` has a primary index `questionUniqueId` and has another column `surveyUniqueId` that maps it to a `survey`

A user creates a new `survey` then adds `surveyQuestions` to it. Each time a surveyQuestion is added an ajax call creates the new row in `surveyQuestions` table.

Now, here's the rub, the user can rearrange the order of the questions on the survey.

**What is the best way to store the order of the questions for each survey?**

For me, two options come to mind:

- **Option 1:** Create a `questionOrder` column on the `surveys` table to store a sorted array of `questionUniqueId`s. Basically, every time the user adds, deletes, or moves a question, send the standard ajax message to save the question and then loop over all questions in the UI creating an ordered list of `questionUniqueId`s and send a second ajax request to update a `questionOrder` column for the `survey`. Later, when building the UI, I can use that list to render the questions in that same order
- **Option 2:** Create a `questionIndex` column on the `surveyQuestions` table to store the index of each question. Basically, when a user adds a new question, simply save that one question with the appropriate index added, then, every time the user deletes or moves a question, loop over all questions in the UI creating and array of question updates and on the server, use the question's index within that update array as it's `questionIndex`

**Some notes:**

- For me, option 2 seems excessive as it requires saving every question row again, when only the index changed.
- `surveyQuestions` can only belong to one `survey`
- a `survey` will never have more than 100 questions
- users can add questions at any index, remove questions, and or re-arrange questions. the UI uses jQuery UI's sortable()
- If it matters, I'm using PHP on the server side

**How would you handle storing the question order? One of these, or some other way I haven't thought of?**

Comment: Close voters, I'm not sure why this would be "primarily opinion-based". Would there not be real world effects in choosing one option over the other, like the expense of updating more rows than necessary?

Comment: Can the user rearrange the questions?  This would add a significant wrinkle into the mix.

Comment: @RickJames indeed, users can add questions at any index, remove questions, and or re-arrange questions. the UI uses jQuery UI's `sortable()`

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the sub-problem of storing/representing ordered items in an RDBMS table:

Another approach is to represent order in terms of "next-in-list", i.e. "the specified element comes after this one" - i.e. a linked-list:

So originally you might have this data:

```
Id    Name       SortOrder
--------------------------
101   Foo        3
102   Bar        1
103   Baz        2
```

It could be stored as:

```
Id    Name       Next
--------------------------
101   Foo        (NULL)
102   Bar        102
103   Baz        101
```

You would need some way of either storing the HEAD item, or iterating through the items to see which items don't have a parent.

The advantage to this approach is that re-ordering a small number of rows, or inserting rows at a given position is cheap: you only need to update two rows instead of the entire range. The downside is that you need to be careful with referential-integrity to avoid missing `Next` rows, as well as duplicates (which would represent a graph-cycle), or rows with incorrectly `NULL` values. Fortunately these can be enforced with a self-foreign-key and a non-NULL filtered UNIQUE constraint, however if you're storing multiple groups in a single table you would also need a custom CHECK constraint to ensure that only 1 row in each group is the tail (NULL), and use a composite-key to prevent a row from one group from referencing another group's row.

You'll also need a CTE to recursively iterate through the `Next` values to find the position to insert at if your application code only knows the "insert at index" value instead of the primary-key of the row to insert after.

Answer (score 1):

If you're ever thinking of storing an "array" in a field on a database, really really really question if it is a good idea.

Sure, with 100 questions you may need to update 100 rows in a worst case re-ordering scenario. But that is 100 INTs (technically could even be SMALLINTs). It might be something you could consider if you were updating variable length string values; but the cost of updating 100 integer values should be minuscule compared to the efforts to maintain (and construct) such an "array" field while maintaining referential integrity.

...and then you have to think about the sacrifices of features databases are great at; instead of `SELECT [fields] FROM [child] WHERE [parent]_id = X ORDER BY [sequence field]` you have to pull X's array, parse it, pull the child values, then sort those by the parsed sequence. And if you want to change that sequence, you have to repack the child identifiers (which means you have to insert the child data to get an identifier before the "client" code can even sequence it.)

Answer (score 1):

(Rewritten)

Each question should have a unique id.  This id has nothing to do with the ordering on the screen.

The order is a list of ids.  This list (I assume) is maintained, shuffled, added to, deleted from, etc by a UI, correct?  There is no use for the list other than deciding which questions to display in what order.

So, the UI gets, modifies, and stores a commalist of question ids.  The contents and order of this list controls the display.  It could be a `TEXT` field, since it is of no use to MySQL, only of use to the UI.  Most app languages can easily implode/explode the list.

Comment: How would this handle a user adding a question in the middle? Say there are 10 questions, and the user adds a new one at index 5.

Comment: Rewrote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When we speak in words of optimization we should clearly understand what do we really should optimize.

1) If you creating some admin panel for public site with surveys Option 1 is the only right choice. Overhead from 100 * x updates that you done while you edit your survey is nothing in compare of simplicity of source code and advantages of order field.

2) If you creating some interface for thoudsands of users that will create millions of surveys with billion of questions - ok, optimisation is needed but still order field is too good to refuse it. So the @Dai solution could be useful in this case.